# Orchard Taxonomies - Get Parent Nodes only

Tags: orchardcms

I have a 'Colours' taxonomy with 2 levels and I am looking to display each parent node as a separate section of the page - separated by an `<h5>` let's say.

My question: How do I get just the parent nodes of the taxonomy? Then secondly, how do I display just the child nodes for that parent term?

I can see from debugging that the Slug is appended on nested items (e.g. `/parent-node/child-node`), but that's as far as I've got.

----UPDATE----
I've noticed that the parent nodes Path value is always '/', then the child nodes proceed it until the next parent node is hit (so long as I don't manually sort it).

So I have overridden my shape as follows:

```
@foreach (var term in terms)
{
    if (term.Path == "/")
    {
        //It's a top-level term - add header
        <h5>@term.Name</h5>
    }
    else
    {
        <div>@term.Name</div>
    }
}
```

This kind of works, but the problem now is that everything is displaying in alphabetical order - and my client wants to change the order.

I could use the weighting system, but I'd like something a bit more robust.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: You mean something like the Taxonomy Menu?

Comment: Thanks @devqon, but I can't use a widget really as I have potentially hundreds of items to create and would need hundreds of matching layers, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taxonomies and Terms are both Containers of Terms. To get only the parent nodes in your Taxonomy you could select all of the Terms that have the Taxonomy as their Container.

```cs
var parentTerms = terms.Where(t => t.Container == myTaxonomy);
```

You could use the same approach to get the children for a parent term (assuming you only want to go one level deep, otherwise you'd have to do this recursively).

```cs
foreach(var parentTerm in parentTerms) {
    var childTerms = terms.Where(t => t.Container == parentTerm);
}
```

Alternatively you could inject Orchard's Taxonomy Service in your Controller:

```cs
public class MyController : Controller {
    private readonly ITaxonomyService _taxonomyService;

    public MyController(ITaxonomyService _taxonomyService) {
        this._taxonomyService = _taxonomyService;
    }
}
```

This gives you access to a couple of useful methods like

```cs
IEnumerable<TermPart> GetParents(TermPart term);
IEnumerable<TermPart> GetChildren(TermPart term);
IEnumerable<TermPart> GetChildren(TermPart term, bool includeParent);
```